# Redis aggregate query with multiple filter conditions

Tags: redis

I'm trying to run an aggregate query while also checking if a hash's position is within a bounding box.

My hash:

```
FT.CREATE idx ON HASH PREFIX 1 "managmentScan:" SCHEMA bin NUMERIC SORTABLE x NUMERIC SORTABLE y NUMERIC SORTABLE grade NUMERIC SORTABLE latest_mngmt TAG SORTABLE

HSET managmentScan:123 bin 123 x 50 y 15 grade 20 latest_mngmt "owner123"
```

So I tried filtering like this and keep getting errors back:

```
> FT.AGGREGATE idx "*" FILTER "@x > 0 AND @x < 100 AND @y > 0 AND @y < 100" GROUPBY 1 @latest_mngmt REDUCE AVG 1 @grade AS average_grade SORTBY 2 @average_grade ASC LIMIT 0 5
"Syntax error at offset 7 near 'AND'"

> FT.AGGREGATE idx "*" FILTER "@x > 0 x < 100 @y > 0 @y < 100" GROUPBY 1 @latest_mngmt REDUCE AVG 1 @grade AS average_grade SORTBY 2 @average_grade ASC LIMIT 0 5
"Syntax error at offset 7 near 'x'"

> FT.AGGREGATE idx "*" FILTER "@x:[0 50] AND @y:[0 50]" GROUPBY 1 @latest_mngmt REDUCE AVG 1 @grade AS average_grade SORTBY 2 @average_grade ASC LIMIT 0 5
"Syntax error at offset 4 near '0'"
```

When I try just one filter it works here:

```
> FT.AGGREGATE idx "*" FILTER "@x > 0" GROUPBY 1 @latest_mngmt REDUCE AVG 1 @grade AS average_grade SORTBY 2 @average_grade ASC LIMIT 0 5
1) "1"
2) 1) "latest_mngmt"
   2) "owner123"
   3) "average_grade"
   4) "20"
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried replacing AND with && and it seems to work now. I don't know why I could not find this online.

```
> FT.AGGREGATE idx "*" FILTER "@x > 0 && @x < 100 && @y > 0 && @y < 100" GROUPBY 1 @latest_mngmt REDUCE AVG 1 @grade AS average_grade SORTBY 2 @average_grade ASC LIMIT 0 5
1) "1"
2) 1) "latest_mngmt"
   2) "owner123"
   3) "average_grade"
   4) "20"
```

Comment: It's here: https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/aggregations/#filter-expressions

Comment: Also, you might want to use the index itself to do this:

`FT.AGGREGATE idx "@x:[0 100] @y:[0 100]" GROUPBY...`